# Mysql Select Statement with respect to another table field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One is newBus, and Second is newPassengers. The table newBus contain the  columns startcity and endCity. Now let say newBus.startCity contains:

```
newBus.id----newBus.startCity-----newBus.endCity
    4             ACity        to     xCity
    5             tCity        to     MCity
```

newPassenger table:
3 passengers wants to go to

```
newPassengers.s_city------newPassengers.e_city
    tCity             to       GCity
    OCity             to       FCity
    tCity             to       MCity
```

I want to select the all passenger who want to go from tCity to MCity but with respect to  newBus.id = 5.

Comment: please tell us table structure and relations.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted the schema for your tables.

Comment: Why is it tagged as Zend-framework or php....? There is nothing in the question regarding these tags.

Comment: "select newtrucks.id, loads.startCity, loads.endCity , loads.weight, loads.company, loads.truckType 
             from loads LEFT join newtrucks ON newtrucks.s_city = loads.startCity 
             where  newtrucks.e_city = loads.endCity and loads.feet <= newtrucks.feet_left and newtrucks.id = '9'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT newPassengers.id 
FROM newBus
    INNER JOIN newPassengers ON newPassengers.s_city = newBus.startCity
WHERE newPassengers.s_city = 'tCity' 
    AND newPassengers.e_city = 'MCity' 
    AND newBus.id = 5
```

This assumes that all passengers will get on a bus that has a start city the same as their start city, and that the ID of the passenger is newPassengers.id  .  You can add more fields to the select list to get the information you are after.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select the all passenger who want to go from tCity to MCity but with respect to newBus.id = 5.

```
SELECT p.id
FROM newpassengers p
INNER JOIN newbus b ON (p.s_city = b.startcity AND p.e_city = b.endCity)
WHERE p.s_city = 'tCity' AND p.e_city = 'MCity' AND b.id = '5';
```